# No Linked You tube account, Code=401 "The operation couldn’t be completed. While Searching videos

Tags: ios, youtube-api

I am using YouTube Data API 2.1.

When I search for video without login everything works fine, I got all the video listed.
But when I try to search after login using an unlinked google account I got

> Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=401 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (  NoLinkedYouTubeAccount
>
> ## NoLinkedYouTubeAccount
>
> ### Error 401
>
> )"
>   UserInfo=0x67cb240 {error= 
>   NoLinkedYouTubeAccount
>
> ## NoLinkedYouTubeAccount
>
> ### Error 401
>
> , NSLocalizedFailureReason=( 
>   NoLinkedYouTubeAccount
>
> ## NoLinkedYouTubeAccount
>
> ### Error 401
>
> )}

But when I create channel it worked fine.

How it is working when logged out, since this requires no user id:( . Also for searching public data no user id is needed as specified in documents.

Anybody faced the same issue? or am I completely wrong?
Please provide some guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the last comment [here](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4928):

> Previously, when using v=2.1 of the YouTube Data API, a "lightweight"
>   YouTube channel would be automatically created when there isn't
>   already a channel for a specific Google Account.
>
> With the transition to linking channels with Google+ profiles, that
>   functionality has been retired. There are no longer auto-created
>   channels, and if you're getting that error, it's because there really
>   isn't an existing channel.

The issue has `WontFix` status and API 2.x has already been [marked](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_clientlogin) as deprecated, I guess the solution for you is to start using the newest API.